# Timestamp conversion and find its difference

Tags: python, python-3.x, timestamp

I have the following two timestamps

```
time1 = 2018-05-13 13:06:30
time2 = 2018-05-14T13:49:37.140Z
```

How to find the difference from it? I am looking for an output that tells the difference in the number of hours in python. The example above case is approx. 23hrs.

Comment: Please, just google "python parse date time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [python datetime model](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Anyway, it looks like you have 2 types of string representations of a date, so:

```
import datetime

time1 = "2018-05-13 13:06:30"
time2 = "2018-05-14T13:49:37.140Z"

time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(time1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(time2, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
print((time2 - time1).total_seconds()/60/60)
```